# space-bar increments string value

Tags: actionscript-3

how to handle space-bar in taking input from user in a string.my code is

```
btnSearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getData);
function getData(event:MouseEvent)
{
   var input:String = textfieldName.text; 
   if((input != null)&&(input.length != 0)&&(input != "")) 
   { 
       func(input); 
   } 
}
```

when user hits backspace, func is called and input string length increased as many times as the spacebar is clicked.

Comment: sorry,could you explain : `... hits backspace, func is called and input string length increased...`

Comment: func should be called only when there is something entered in it except the empty string but by clicking spacebar func is calling with empty space of length 1

Comment: `String input = ` is not ECMAScript - that looks more like Java/C#,  I think you want `var input:String = `

Comment: Post more of your code. where are you listening for the textChange/input?

Comment: whole code is...


btnSearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getData); 

function getData(event:MouseEvent) {
 
   var input:String = textfieldName.text;      
   if((input != null)&&(input.length != 0)&&(input != ""))     
   {         
     func(input);     
   } 
}

when search button is clicked the value of input string is passed to func only if it is not empty...but when user hits spacebar and clicks search button the func is calling with length of one....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to di first is to validate the input, e.g. you can trim all white space (you could also do it on the textfield e.g. by applying the allowed characters to the restrict property

```
textfieldName.restrict = "0-9";//this will restrict to only integer values
```

to strip in your getData handler you could do as follows:

```
//trim begin
while(input && input.charAt(0) == " ")
{
    input = input.substr(1);
}
```

placed after you read the input value from textfield.

best regards